# if I delete a namespace will it automatically delete the resources in the cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I am learning Kubernetes and I deleted a namespace and it automatically deleted resources assigned to it, what happens if someone deletes it by accident. Is there control over this, except for changing permissions?

Comment: https://devops.stackexchange.com/ might be a good place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Yaml files to define your resources,  if your pods are stateless no problem to recreate your namespace, your PV volumes, your data is no-namespaced, so you dont loose it.